# React - REST : javascript fetch posts empty body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

```
fetch(REST+'/signup', {
    mode: 'cors',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({ id: id, pw: pw }) 
}).then(async (res) => {
    let json = await res.json();
    if (json.result === true) { 
        this.setState({ view: 'login' });
    } 
});
```

this is my client's POST request part.
my react app uses port 3000
and my REST server is using 80

I already declared using cors in my REST server like this

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors()); // enable CORS to prevent same origin policy error
```

and this is rest of my REST server code

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    ...
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        result: true
    }));
});
```

when I used cURL to test REST server, it says

```
$ curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"id": "gksrlf2ek", "pw": "hangil2da!"}' http://localhost/signup
{"result":true}
```

but using my react app, REST server gets {}. empty object.

Comment: It does post something. REST server gets something. The problem here is what REST server gets is empty json {}.

Comment: You are specifying `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` in the headers, but sending text (JSON.stringify produces a string). So, either remove `JSON.stringify` or change the Content-Type to text.

Comment: @JeremyThille I tried what you said.
But when I changed content type to text, server got {}
And deleting stringify sends '[object Object]' literally.

Comment: Sorry. Reason for this problem was that id and pw was undefined value and JSON.stringify did return {}.
So the code was working well..
However thanks for you help @JeremyThille

Comment: @JeremyThille `'application/json'` is supposed to be a string. You can't send JavaScript objects over the network

Comment: @TJ I never bother stringifyting my objects. I just go `await fetch(url, object, { method:'post'});`, job done. And I get my object directly in the back-end, without stringifying or parsing. Maybe these are automatic under the hood, I don't know.

Comment: AAAAAH OP maybe that's why you're not getting anything. You're sending data in the option's body, when it's supposed to be `fetch( url, data, options )`, amirite?